# How to make a many to many links without altering the record object

Tags: django, django-models

I feel like I am missing something basic here but I can't figure it out. I will give a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve. Take this typical restaurant example for instance.

If I have pizza table that is populated with records of pizza names. Another table is records pizza-toppings. They have a many to many relationship. If a customer orders the "2 Topping" with "Pepperoni" and "Mushrooms", then in the backend, some script would get the "2 Topping" pizza object and get the two topping objects and then link/add/relate them. So that `pizza.toppings.all()` would return a QuerySet of the two topping.

If a different customer at shortly after orders the exact same pizza. The previously added toppings will already be linked to that pizza object. Obviously it's not practical to clear relationships after every order has been made.

```py
##Model

class Pizza(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField('Topping', related_name='pizzas'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Topping(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

## Logic

cheese_pizza = Pizza.objects.create(name='Cheese')
mozzarella = Topping.objects.create(name='mozzarella')
mozzarella.pizzas.add(cheese_pizza)

mozzarella.pizzas.all() -> <QuerySet [<Pizza: Cheese>]>
```

How can I add pizza objects, with toppings linked, to an Orders table without affecting the original pizza objects in the Pizza table, such that `Pizza.objects.get(name="2 Topping")` will always return an object with no topping objects linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A customer orders the "2 Topping" with "Pepperoni" and "Mushrooms"...

The normal way to model this would be to have the toppings as part of the order. `Pizza` and `Topping` are then *types* of thing, while an `Order` records the specific choices made on each order.

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Order(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField('Topping', related_name='orders')
```

If it's the case that some pizzas have their toppings baked in (so to speak), you could have toppings as part of both `Pizza` and `Order`, perhaps with some additional information indicating how many toppings are allowed, for validation. Since this obviously isn't your real code, though, it's hard to say what the best way to model the problem is.

Comment: This is a similar conclusion to the which one I came to. It is good to get confirmation of this. Indeed, the real problem is more complex than this, however, this is main concept that I was trying to get my head around. Thank you very much for the help.